# Expand $(\tan x - \sqrt{3})(3\tan x + \sqrt{3})$

Tags: trigonometry

Will someone show me the steps to expanding $(\tan x - \sqrt{3})(3\tan x + \sqrt{3})$.

I have tried FOIL, but I get the wrong answer.

I keep getting $-3\sqrt{3}\tan x$ instead of $-2\sqrt{3}\tan x$.

Comment: Then post your steps, so that we know at which step you get it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(\tan x - \sqrt{3})(3\tan x + \sqrt{3})&=\tan x\cdot3\tan x-\sqrt3\cdot3\tan x+\tan x\cdot\sqrt3-\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt3\\&=3\tan^2x-3\sqrt3\tan x+\sqrt3\tan x-3\\&=3\tan^2x-2\sqrt3\tan x-3\end{align}$$

Comment: an $x$ is missing

Comment: What happens to the second $3$ in the problem in the second phase?

Comment: @WilliamZlacki $-3\sqrt3\tan x+\sqrt3\tan x=-2\sqrt3\tan x$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Oh I left it out when I did the addition, sorry. But yes, you're right, thanks.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, Looking back, now I seem, too, have misplaced my steps so called once or twice now I need help one more time on this since i didn't type it in up there.

Comment: @WilliamZlacki I couldn't understand that comment, sorry. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Nvm, figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

$$(tanx -\sqrt {3})(3tanx +\sqrt {3})$$
$$3tan^2 x+\sqrt {3} tanx -3\sqrt {3} tanx -3$$
$$3tan^2 x-2\sqrt {3} tanx-3$$
This is the expanded form..

.....--))

Answer (score 1):

it is $$3\tan(x)^2-3\sqrt{3}\tan(x)+\sqrt{3}\tan(x)-3=3\tan(x)^2-2\sqrt{3}\tan(x)-3$$

Comment: $$\sqrt{3}\tan(x)-3\sqrt{3}\tan(x)=-2\sqrt{3}\tan(x)$$